# How to check if a column exists in a table in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to find if a column exists using an IF condition.

If it does not exist add the column.

If it does exist then update the column.

How do I check if the column exists in a particular table in a database in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: You  can use IF COL_LENGTH('TABLENAME','COLUMNNAME') IS NOT NULL PRINT 'Existed'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.name as TabName
    ,c.name as ColName
FROM sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name like '%COLUMN_NAME%'
    AND t.name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```